# TabItem tag value is null

Tags: android, xml, tags, android-tablayout

I want to make some action with my TabItems in my TabLayout depend of it Tags. The listener works properly and when i turn on Debug i can see that selected tab have proper name/icon/view etc. but the tag value is null.

code:

```
 bottomTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
               Log.i(TAG,tab.getTag().toString()+"");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

XML

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
            android:tag="@string/TAG"
            android:text="@string/tab1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:icon="@drawable/my_icon2"
            android:tag="@string/TAG2"
            android:text="@string/tab2" />

 </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Comment: isn't it supposed to be `getText()` instead of `getTag()`

Comment: i dont want to getText of my item but getTag to proper interpret this in my logic.